# SQL query will not list duplicate rows

Tags: php, sql, database, odbc

Following [this guide](https://chartio.com/learn/databases/how-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table/) here and transposing to my column names

This query works and will return expected results, counting duplicate rows:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NAME,REQUIRED_DATE,DELIVERY_POSTCODE, COUNT(*) 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NAME,REQUIRED_DATE,DELIVERY_POSTCODE HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
```

However modifying the query to fit the second example in the guide I am following as such:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM my_table a
JOIN (SELECT ACCOUNT_NAME, REQUIRED_DATE, COUNT(*)
FROM my_table  
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NAME, REQUIRED_DATE
HAVING count(*) > 1 ) b
ON a.ACCOUNT_NAME = b.ACCOUNT_NAME
AND a.REQUIRED_DATE = b.REQUIRED_DATE
ORDER BY a.ACCOUNT_NAME
```

Simply returns false.

I am using PHP and connecting to an external database through an ODBC connector if that makes any difference?

Php code as requested:

```
$conn = @odbc_connect(
    "****",
    "****", "****");
if (!($conn)) {
    echo "<p>Connection to DB via ODBC failed ";
    echo odbc_errormsg ($conn);
    echo "</p>\n";
} else {

    echo "<p>Connection to DB via ODBC succeeded </p>\n";

};
```

Using the first query:

```
$sql = "SELECT ACCOUNT_NAME,REQUIRED_DATE,DELIVERY_POSTCODE, COUNT(*) 
FROM my_table GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NAME,REQUIRED_DATE,DELIVERY_POSTCODE HAVING COUNT (*) > 1";

$rs = @odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

var_dump($rs);
```

I receive:

```
resource(3) of type (odbc result)
```

Which contains the data I expect. Using the second query:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.*
FROM my_table a
JOIN (SELECT ACCOUNT_NAME, REQUIRED_DATE, COUNT(*)
FROM my_table  
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NAME, REQUIRED_DATE
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) b
ON a.ACCOUNT_NAME = b.ACCOUNT_NAME
AND a.REQUIRED_DATE = b.REQUIRED_DATE
ORDER BY a.ACCOUNT_NAME";

$rs = @odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

var_dump($rs);
```

I receive:

```
bool(false)
```

Thanks to kainaw's comment I have fetched the error message and it does report a syntax error:

```
Error ID: 21 Severity: ERROR Facility: DBCAPERR - SQL Syntax error.
```

I believe this is the cause of the issue:

"Standard table join syntax used in the SQL Query is not supported by Rocket U2 database"

Comment: Please add the php code, without the credentials of DB connection

Comment: If the query did not find any results, it would return an empty set. By returning false, it means that there was an error in your SQL eury. It is very very VERY likely that the query you typed into this question is not absolutely identical to the one in your PHP code. You should fetch the SQL error in your code so you can see why the SQL query failed.

Comment: You appear to be correct and I have edited the post with some more info. However I can assure you that the code displayed above is *exactly* what I have in my code so any syntax errors should be in there too